# buttons-checkbox bootstrap in form filter for Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I want to use bootstrap buttons for filter cateogries in wordpress and I don't know what is the best way to do it.

This is my markup:

```
<?php $categorias = get_categories();?>

 <form method="post" action="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">
   <div class="btn-group" data-toggle-name="cat" data-toggle="buttons-checkbox" >
        <label class="control-label" for="inputIcon">Selecciona entre las categorias</label>
        <?php 
             foreach( $categorias as $cat):
                echo '<button type="button" class="btn" rel="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="Seleccionar" value="'.$cat->term_id.'">'.$cat->name.'</button>';
             endforeach;
        ?>
            <input type="hidden" value="" name="cat">
            <button class="btn" type="submit" >enviar</button>
   </div>

  </form>
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: That's not a programmer's question, but asking for someone to develop a feature for you. Please either try it yourself and come back with more specific questions indicating what you tried and where you failed, or pay someone to do this.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    foreach( $categorias as $cat):
        $cat_link = get_category_link( $cat->cat_ID );
                echo '<a class="btn" href="'.$cat_link.'">'.$cat->name.'</a>';
             endforeach;
?>
```

should be enough to create some buttons with link to category.

if you must use a form then do this

```
<input type="hidden" name="filter-category" id="filter-category" value="0" >
<?php
    foreach( $categorias as $cat):
        $cat_link = get_category_link( $cat->cat_ID );
                echo '<button type="button" class="btn filter-category" value="'.$cat->cat_ID.'">'.$cat->name.'</button>';
             endforeach;
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.filter-category').on('click', function() {
        cat = $(this).val();
        $('#filter-category').val(cat);
    });
});
</script>
```

then you POST your category ID with that hidden input.